# Batch-renaming "complicated" files names

Tags: bash, substring, batch-rename

I am having a hard time with this issue.

I've got several files in a folder with the general name format:

> **[** *file type* **]** *file name* **(** *date* **)** *file specs* **.** *file extension*

- *File type* can be anything such as: Webinar, Presentation, Symposium, Oral Talk etc... Please notice that it is surrounded by [] and might include spaces.
- *File name* can be anything, please notice it might include spaces.
- *Date* is in the general format dd_mm_yyyy. Please notice that it is surrounded by ().
- *File specs* gives general information about the file attributes (and is not important.

I want to write a script so I could rename all files inside the folder to the following format:

> *date* **[** *file type* **]** *file name* **.** *file extension*

() around date should be discarded, the date should change for format ddmmyyyy, [] around file type should be maintained, and *file specs* should be ignored.

**Example:**

```
[Oral Talk] Prospects for future research (13_11_2017) 1080p 320kpbs.mp4
```

should change to:

```
13112017 [Oral Talk] Prospects for future research.mp4
```

But then, this should be iterated for all files in the folder.

Comment: The general description is helpful, but concrete examples would be helpful as well. The code you've tried and specific problems you've had with it wouldn't hurt either; see docs on building a [mcve].

Comment: ...the advantage a MCVE adds is that, done right, it lets people concretely test their answers -- if for given inputs X1, X2 and X3 they get outputs Y1, Y2 and Y3, then one can be certain that a given answer meets spec.

Comment: (Also, showing the code you've tried lets us know what parts of the problem you already know how to solve -- we don't need to go into a description of what a regular expression is if you're already using 'em).

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I would rather treat this from ground zero. I have been playing with ls, grep, awk and print, but I got nothing worth mentioning.

Comment: Re: "I want to write a script so I could rename all files inside the folder"... As said before, you should at least show us your attempted efforts.

Comment: As an aside -- `ls` is [very much the wrong tool](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for programmatic use; its output is designed to be parsed by humans, not scripts -- even with `-1`, names that confuse it can exist..

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use a regular expression with match groups to pick out pieces of the name
re='\[(.+)\] (.+) [(]([[:digit:]_]+)[)](.*)[.]([[:alnum:]]+)'
#     1      2        3                4       5

# if we were passed a directory name, change to it before running
if [[ $1 ]]; then cd -- "$1" || exit; fi

for name in *.*; do
  if [[ $name =~ $re ]]; then
    date=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    ext=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
    type=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    topic=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    new_name="${date//_/} [$type] $topic.$ext"
    printf 'Renaming %q to %q\n' "$name" "$new_name" >&2
    [[ $dry_run ]] || mv -- "$name" "$new_name"
  else
    printf 'Filename %q does not match pattern; ignoring\n' "$name" >&2
  fi
done
```

If saved under the name `renaming-script` and run as:

```
dry_run=1 ./renaming-script directory-to-rename
```

...this will merely print a report of which contents it *would* rename. With the `dry_run=1` removed, it actually performs those rename operations.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot!
One last request: I have enabled the Linux subsystem in Windows 10, now I would like to put this script inside a folder then make it double-clickable so it will run in that folder. I tried simply placing it there but it won't run, I believe that is because the file cannot be run since it is not in the bin folder. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Generally speaking, being "double-clickable" shouldn't depend on which directory something is in -- if I were to guess (and I can only guess, without more details -- and without being particularly familiar with the Linux subsystem and how processes within it are spawned), I'd hazard that file permissions probably need to be adjusted, as with `chmod +x`.

Comment: I understand that, what I meant by 'double-clickable' is actually executable from that folder. I can double-click the script file and ask Windows to open it with bash, but I believe it will (try to) run as if bash opened in my User folder. First, it won't recognize that the file is to be run (as the initial './' is missing), then it cannot understand that I am running it from another folder altogether.

Comment: If *that's* your problem, then what you need is [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: I need a small fix. [Date] in the new_name should be mmddyyyy. I tried changing the code to
re='\[(.+)\] (.+) [(][[:digit:]][_][[:digit:]][_][[:digit:]][)](.*)[.]([[:alnum:]]+)'
then reassembling accordingly but had no success. (The code does not recognize the original names as valid.)

Comment: Don't. Really. `mmddyyyy` is going to make massive headaches, and you shouldn't ever use it. With `yyyymmdd`, ASCII sort order is exactly the same as date sort order, and this gets you lots of useful characteristics (you can just use GNU `sort` to put filenames in order, they'll come out right in `ls`, you can compare with `[[ $name < $date ]]` or `[[ $name >  $date ]]`, etc).

Comment: Great idea, thank you. I figured I forgot to add () around [[:digit:]] to extract the string so I could get it later with BASH_REMATCH. Now everything is working as desired. :)
Out of curiosity, what '.+' and '.*' mean?

Comment: `.` means "match any one character"; `+` means "one or more of the preceding thing"; `*` means "zero or more of the preceding thing". So `.+` means "match one or more characters, no matter what they are", and `.*` means "match any number of characters -- including zero -- no matter what they are".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression -- the relevant version here is "POSIX extended".